# How can I make a QWidget semitransparent to events?

Tags: qt

I've seen similar questions but no answers that fit what I need.  I want an invisible widget that lives on top of my whole application (no problems here).  I want this widget to catch events so that I can print stuff about them, record them, whatever.  I currently have an event filter hooked up that does this just fine.  Then I want it to let the event go through to whatever is behind the widget.  So for instance, if I try to push a button, the invisible widget should notice that a press happened on that spot, and then the button should actually be pressed.  Can this be done in a simple way, or am I going to have to write code to simulate all the events beneath the invisible widget?

Comment: Why not install an event filter?

Comment: I have an event filter installed on the widget, which is how I'm handling the events it receives.  How can I get the filter to pass the event to widgets beneath the top one?  I don't want to pass the event to the parent object, but to the widgets in the space beneath the invisible widget.

Comment: Why don't you just handle the event and then emit a signal that is connected to your invisible widget.

Comment: I think you may be missing what I'm trying to do.  The invisible widget's filter will catch the event, and then I want whatever is behind the invisible widget to also catch the event.  I won't know what object(s) are back there, so I can't just hook them up to a specific slot.

Comment: Return `true` from `eventFilter()` - this tells the event loop to forward the event further. Otherwise the event is consumed.

Comment: You can even filter, consume certain events and forward others, after all it is an event filter.

Comment: No dice.  The Qt API for QObject::eventfilter() says: "In your reimplementation of this function, if you want to filter the event out, i.e. stop it being handled further, return true; otherwise return false."  However, I've tried returning false as well, to no avail.  Either way, it appears to eat the event.

Comment: Ah yes, it makes sense, return `true` if the event was filtered. As of why this doesn't work for you - your widget probably needs to be in active focus to receive events.

Comment: Does returning false forward the event underneath this widget physically, or does it forward the event to the parent widget?  I assume you have to actually call <ParentClass>::eventFilter(obj, event) to forward to the parent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From all the information you disclosed in the comments, I suggest you filter the event as previously discussed, and then use [QCoreApplication::sendEvent](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qcoreapplication.html#sendEvent) to forward the desired events to the invisible widget. It will then propagate the event accordingly to its children.

EDIT: OK, here is quick example that includes a QObject based event filter, that will filter the events for a widget, if the event is mouse event, it will be left for the widget to handle and print the output, if the event is a key event, it will be filtered and not forwarded back to the widget:

The event filter class:

```
    class EventInfo : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit EventInfo(QObject *parent = 0) : QObject(parent) {}

    bool eventFilter(QObject *, QEvent *e) {
        if (e->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonRelease){
            qDebug() << "click event not filtered";
            return false;
        }
        if (e->type() == QEvent::KeyRelease) {
            QKeyEvent *event = static_cast<QKeyEvent *>(e);
            if (event) qDebug() << "key" << event->key() << "filtered";
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
};
```

The widget:

```
class Widget : public QWidget {
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Widget(QWidget *parent = 0) : QWidget(parent) {}

protected:
    void mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *e) {
        qDebug() << "widget clicked at position" << e->pos();
    }

    void keyReleaseEvent(QKeyEvent *e) {
        qDebug() << "pressed key" << e->key();
    }
};
```

main.cpp:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Widget w;
    EventInfo info;
    w.installEventFilter(&info);
    w.show();    
    return a.exec();
}
```

Testing output to show that keyboard events are filtered and mouse press events are forwarded to the widget:

```
click event not filtered
widget clicked at position QPoint(352,230) 

key 70 filtered 

click event not filtered
widget clicked at position QPoint(405,163) 

key 87 filtered
```

Comment: The invisible widget is the one catching the events in the first place.  I need the events to forward behind it to visible widgets.  However, there might be a proper parent I can forward them to.  I'll investigate!

Comment: You can forward to any widget, it does not have to be a part of the current parent-child hierarchy.

Comment: I'm trying to trick it right now by hiding the invisible widget and then forwarding the event to the widget at the same spot as the event, then showing the invisible widget again.

Comment: Ummm, maybe that is just me, but how do you "show" the invisible :)

Comment: Hah. Well, I don't think this will work that way, because the invisible widget shows before the event is complete (and thus receives the event again).  Is there any way to specify that I want a widget at pos x,y and below a certain z-value or something?

Comment: @Brianide I updated my answer with an example. The filter is not an invisible widget, but you'll get the point.

Comment: Yeah, I'm with you so far.  The problem is that I have unrelated widgets behind this one, and I need the events to go to them.  So I'm messing with QApplication::sendEvent() to do so.  I've used qApp->widgetAt(ev->pos()) to acquire the proper widget, and my debugs show that I'm looking at the proper one.  However, my sendEvent() doesn't appear to be having any effect...  I tried postEvent, as well, and it crashed.  I'm sure sendEvent() should work, but something must be wrong on my end.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to put together the example, by the way.

Comment: `sendEvent` does work, you are probably not using it correctly, you should probably do some design considerations, because the way you describe your current situation it doesn't feel like it is well designed.

Comment: I'll see what I can figure out.  Thanks again for all the help.

Comment: I got it working.  For some reason, QCoreApplication::sendEvent() seems to work when QApplication::sendEvent() didn't.

Comment: `QApplication` doesn't have such a method, it is inherited directly from `QCoreApplication`, it is literally the same function, so this is strange.

Comment: It probably was working, but I wasn't translating the coordinates to the child widget's local system.  It's all good now though.