# How to install event filters

Tags: c++, qt, events

I have a custom widget `A` within another custom widget `B`. Widget `A` normally has a mousePressEvent where I open a context menu. But now as it is in widget `B`, I want to open widget `B`'s context menu and intercept the event so that only B knows it.

If I use this code in class B after adding an instance of A to B:

```
this->installEventFilter(instanceOf_A);
```

Or

```
instanceOf_A->installEventFilter(this);
```

Where

```
A::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *e){
    if (e->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonPress){
    QMouseEvent *mouseEvent = static_cast<QMouseEvent *>(e);
    if (mouseEvent->button() == Qt::RightButton){
        qDebug()<<"  Right mouse button press detected. \
                     Return true, now child should not get the mouse event";
        return true;
    }
}
```

Nothing works. Also `return false` , `e->accept()`, `e->ignore()` don't work or show any impact. How do you setup an eventFilter? Where? In `A` or `B`?

EDIT: replaced the `e->MouseButtonPress`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16069936/how-can-i-make-a-qwidget-semitransparent-to-events/16084075#16084075

Comment: I deleted my answer because it seems that I misunderstood something. Yes, I mentioned very big mistake in your code but it was not enough to solve the problem. Sorry.

Comment: When I think about it... you don't even need the event filter, just process the event according to whether A is on its own or in B. Needless to say, but it will not only be B that knows about it, but it will be where the even triggers an action, with A serving just to redirect the event in case of being a child of B.

Comment: Right now I figured the same. I don't need the filter. But I figured a) it makes no difference if I install it on A or B unless it is the same filter (only object name changes), and b) Contrary to your linked example code, in both cases the mousePressEvent of widget A is called BEFORE the eventFilter. I don't understand, why. I was expecting that the eventFilter filters it BEFORE widget A's own handler.

Comment: `the mousePressEvent of widget A is called BEFORE the eventFilter.` I can't make this happen, and it should not happen. That would ruin the whole point of the event filter.

Comment: Okay so it is intended this way. I understood it as if the point of an event filter was to filter events before they reach the handlers.

Comment: @user2366975 That is exactly what I said. Event filter should receive the events before they go to the handlers. Otherwise it wouldn't be a filter.

Comment: So in my case it does not work as expected. The `mousePressEvent` of `A` gets called before the filter I've installed on `A`.

Comment: @user2366975 Yes, that is not how it should work. There is something wrong in your case.

Comment: Could this be related to parent widgets (there are more than only B) that also have an eventFilter installed?

Comment: It shouldn't matter as far as I know. Events are propagated from the child to the parent, not the other way around. You could still try removing the event filters from those objects and see if anything changes.